# How to make a full height-device banner in html?

Tags: html

Hi I'm trying to make a full height banner for my website's homepage. I want my banner to always take the full height of the window, wether on computer, ipad or iphones. Anyone could help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try googling "vh css units", it may help. In summary, make a div with 100vh height. If it's not in the flow with the content you can also use "position: fixed".

Comment: And if you have an image in the background use `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 1):

You can give `height:100vh` to the banner. So that it will cover the whole window.

Answer (score 0):

if your banner  contains only an image ,it can be done by:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    } 
    .banner-div{
        background-size: 100% 100%; 
        background-image: url(http://www.wefms.com/speedtest/hello.JPG);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
</style>    

 </head> 
 <body>
 <div class="banner-div"> 
      <!--displays an image banner for full screen size-->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

or it can be done by

```
<head>
    <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;

            }
          .banner{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color:lightblue;

          }
          .inner-div{
            background-color: lightgreen;
            width: 200px;
          }
          .normal-div{
            height: 140vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: lightgreen;
          }
        </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="banner"> 
      <div class="inner-div">banner div for full  screen height</div>
  </div>

  <div id="normal-div">
      Normal division for 140 vh
  </div>

</body>
```

or you can also use javascript

```
 screen.height
```

to detect device screen height and you can assign it to a div